# It is possible TO display data in a single Row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I want to display data in a single row like

```
TokenNo:AS894,NCBYPA:3,NCBYQA:1,NCBYIED:1 

TokenNo NCBYPA  NCBYQA  NCBYIED
AS894       0   0   1
AS894       3   0   0
AS894       0   1   0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Edit your question and put your query *as text* in the question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.  That is, the `case` is the argument to the aggregation function:

```
select tokenNo,
       sum(case when category = 'NC by PA' then 1 else 0 end) as ncbypa,
       . . .   -- and so one for the other columns
from employeeNC
group by tokenNo
```